# Social CRM application that integrates...

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any Social CRM application that integrates the following:

- Telephone calls
- Email comments on Facebook fan pages
- Twitter mentions of my brand

Answer (score 1):

Check out [BatchBook](http://batchbook.com).  I'm not sure what you mean by tracking telephone calls (integrated?) -- they do have a slick twitter module in the dashboard.